# Recording CCI-flagged content with CableCARD tuner to NAS drive

Tags: nas, tv, kodi, dvr

Has anyone been able to record CCI 0x02 programming to a NAS drive with a CableCARD tuner, like Ceton's InfiniTV or the Hauppauge WinTV DCR-2650? And have any ARGUS TV or PseudoTV deployments with XBMC successfully integrated recording via a CableCARD tuner from the XBMC UI?